# All Child Objects of account with the relationship type

Tags: apex, community

I am trying to get all the child objects of account with the type of relationship between them like lookup, master-detail.

I have tried to do so with the below code and i am getting all the objects but not the type of relationship.

```
List<Schema.ChildRelationship>accChildRelationships =Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().childRelationships; 
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(accChildRelationships));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to tell is to check isRestrictedDelete() and isCascadeDelete(). When both of these are true, it is a Master-Detail relationship. If not, it is a lookup.